# Span Poco logging file into subdirectories

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I heed to create a logging system which puts files in with the following directory structure:

```
ROOT
  |- YEAR
      |- MONTH
           |- DAY 1
           |- DAY 2
           |- DAY n
```

Is possible using POCO logger?

Regards,
Daniele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box. It would need a custom archiving strategy inheriting from Poco::ArchiveStrategy;  however, a modification to Poco::FileChannel would be needed to recognize this strategy through a property name/value.

Or, you could write your own alternative to FileChannel that does what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. Maybe I'll made a request to POCO devs. For now I'll settle to use a daily rotation.